# GNU Radio transmission for a set amount of time

Tags: gnuradio, dsp

I am trying to transmit a signal in gnu radio and after a set amount of time have the transmission cut off. For simple example, I have a sine wave that I want to transmit for 30 seconds then after that I want the transmission to cut off. Is there a block that can do that or a combination of blocks I can trick into doing that or anyone with a custom block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Head block does that: End the operation of the flow graph after an amount of samples have passed. Since your sample rate is fixed, that's the way you want to go.

Comment: So you are saying I can enter that in max number of outputs in the options block? Could I do that by multiplying my sample rate by the time I want to run until cut off to do the # of samples. For example, my sample rate is 48 kHz and I want to wait 30 sec before cut off I could do max outputs = sample rate * 30 sec?

Comment: Never mind I see there is actually a block called head. I thought you were referencing top block. I see that it actually works to cut the transmission. Unfortunately, I do not have any hardware to work with right now and just using QT GUI. When the transmission stops, the GUI is max holding at the last value; will this happen with hardware or will it zero out?